# Opening a different dropdown content on a different button

Tags: html, css, button, dropdown

I have this drop down which looks like this

[image]

Now when I click on Add Equipment everything works fine, but when I click on the Deployed Equipments the dropdown of the Add Equipment drops down.

Basically this is what happens when I click Deployed Equipments

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my css:

```css
 /* Dropdown Button */
 .dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
 .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
 }

 /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
 .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
 .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 /* Links inside the dropdown */
 .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
 }

 /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
 .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

 /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
 .show {display:block;}
```

Here's my html:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Add Equipment</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Deployed Equipments</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```js
<script>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code for `myFunction()`?

Comment: @MohammadUsman Added my javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `divs` have same id `myDropdown`. You can remove `ids` for the `div` and use the below code to access the dropdown using `nextElementSibling` of the clicked button. Hope this helps.

```
function myFunction() {
    //Remove class 'show' for dropdown except the current one
    [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")).map(function(el){
         if (this.event.target.nextElementSibling !== el)
            el.classList.remove("show");
    });

    //this.event.target refers to the button clicked. Get nextelement and toggle class 'show'
    this.event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function myFunction() {
 [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")).map(function(el){
  if (this.event.target.nextElementSibling !== el)
   el.classList.remove("show");
 });

 this.event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function (event) {
 if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")).map(function(el){
    el.classList.remove("show");
  });
 }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
 padding: 16px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
 background-color: #3e8e41;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
 color: black;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #f1f1f1
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Add Equipment</button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Deployed Equipments</button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the same ID for 2 different elements on the same page. `myDropdown` appears to be on both.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a solution made using jQuery:

```js
$('.dropdown').click(function() {
 $(this).find(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
 /* Dropdown Button */
 .dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
 .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
 }

 /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
 .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
 .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
 }

 /* Links inside the dropdown */
 .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
 }

 /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
 .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

 /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
 .show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Add Equipment</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Deployed Equipments</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```